# Xamarin.Formsで共用体のコピーに失敗する

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

電文を構造体に変換するのに共用体を使用して上手く行かないのでどなたか助けてください
C言語のように気軽に考えていたのですが、どうも同じような考えではダメなようです

単純に構造体に入っている値を共用体を経由して配列に渡したいだけです

こちらのサンプルはheadと言う変数の内容をuni.headにコピーするだけですがそこでクラッシュし、プログラムが停止します
そのさい、catchにも移動せずにプログラムが停止します
同じ型のhead2にコピーするのは成功しています
uni.head内のメンバ変数に単純に値を代入するのも同様にプログラムが停止します

変換関数を真面目に書けばいいだけなのですが、この様な共用体の挙動について何故こうなるのか教えていただければと思います

```
/// <summary>
/// 電文構造体 ヘッダ
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TMsgHead
{
    public ushort a;
    public ushort b;
    public byte c;
    public byte d;
    public byte rsv1;
    public byte rsv2;
}

/// <summary>
/// 変換用構造体
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct TMsgHeadUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public TMsgHead head;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)] 
    [FieldOffset(0)] public byte[] Hairetsu;
}

/// <summary>
/// ボタンでテスト
/// </summary>
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TMsgHead head = new TMsgHead();
    TMsgHead head2;
    
    head.a = 1;
    head.b = 2;
    head.c = 3;
    head.d = 4;

    TMsgHeadUnion uni = new TMsgHeadUnion();
    uni.head = new TMsgHead();
    try
    {
        head2 = head;       //★コピー成功する
        uni.head = head;    //★エラーになり、catchにも飛ばない、プログラム停止
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.ToString();
    }
    uni.head.a = 3;         //★エラーになり、プログラム停止
    uni.Hairetsu = new byte[8];
    byte[] t = new byte[8];
    Array.Copy(uni.Hairetsu, t, 8);
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 Ver 16.8.3 ではそのコード、そもそも実行できないっス。オフセット 0 に不適切に整列されたか、オブジェクト以外のフィールドでオーバーラップされたオブジェクト フィールドが含まれています。という `System.TypeLoadExcetion` が発生するっス。まあ普通に考えて参照型を含めてしまってはダメなのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。楽をしないで真面目に変換関数を作ることにしました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) の「配列」は参照型なので、提示 `TMsgHeadUnion` は [c](/questions/tagged/c) 流に書くと

```
union TMsgHeadUnion {
    TMsgHead head;
    byte* Hairetsu; // byte Hairetsu[8] ではない
};
```

になります。あなたのやりたいこととは異なっている可能性が高いです。具体的に何をどうしたいのか微妙に想像つきませんが、素直に変換関数を書くほうがよさそうな気がします。

[c](/questions/tagged/c) でも通信電文（バイトの列）を `union` を使って複数バイト型に直接変換しようとするとエンディアン問題が発生しますので異 CPU への移植性がなくなります。（組み込み系ではコストダウンでマイコン変更を行うことがあります）エンディアネスにべたべたに依存するコードは書かないほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: 配列が参照専用でしたか・・・・
大人しく変換関数を真面目に作ります

Comment: 「参照専用」って言い方だとなんだか readonly のように見えますけど、この場合は違うっスよ。「参照型」と「値型」は C# (や Java) を理解する上では超重要事項なので要勉強。